# Fail2ban logging to systemd

Tags: systemd, fail2ban

I am trying to set the fail2ban's backend to systemd.
File:

```
/etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

Option:

```
backend = systemd
```

And it won't start, logs:

```
2018-06-27 12:09:53,387 fail2ban.jail           [10240]: ERROR   Backend 'systemd' failed to initialize due to No module named 'systemd'
```

What could be the solution?

I tried these:

```
python3 -c 'from systemd import journal; print("OK")'
python2 -c 'from systemd import journal; print "OK"'


ImportError: No module named systemd
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to install the module, as stated here: [https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2015-July/033443.html](http://[systemd-devel]%20HEADS-UP:%20splitting%20python-systemd%20out)

The Module can be found here: [https://github.com/systemd/python-systemd](http://python-systemd)

If you're using a debian-like OS (like Ubuntu), you can install the module, depending on your used python version:

```
sudo apt install python-systemd
sudo apt install python3-systemd
```